# Run method before loading ApplicationContext with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm a new engineer working on a large legacy system tasked with setting up a series of unit tests making use of the application's existing Spring configuration. This legacy system depends on an additional configuration system called `LegacyConfig` that pre-dates the adoption of Spring. As the adoption of Spring was built on top of `LegacyConfig`, many of the bean definitions depend on this configuration system already having been initialized through the use of expressions in XML definitions. This `LegacyConfig` is typically initialized in our existing unit tests with a single call: `LegacyConfig.initialize()`.

I have my unit test class set up like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {LegacySystemConfig.class, TestClass.BeanConfig.class})
public class TestClass {
    @Autowired
    SomeTestingDependency someTestingDependency;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        ...
    }
    ....
    @Configuration
    static class BeanConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public OutsideServiceClient mockServiceClient() {
            return Mockito.mock(OutsideServiceClient.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Since we have this dependency on `LegacyConfig` having been initialized, attempting to run the tests results in a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` exception as the Spring configuration attempts to fetch a value from `LegacyConfig`, receives null instead, and fails to convert null to a primitive boolean.

I've attempted to place the `LegacyConfig` initialization within the `setup()` method, but this fails because the ApplicationContext is attempted be loaded before `setup()` is called, resulting in the exception again.

Is there a way for me to run the `LegacyConfig` setup before the test runner or ApplicationContext are initialized?

Comment: Can you not add `LegacyConfig` to one of your `@Configuration` classes?

Comment: I'm supposed to avoid modifying `LegacySystemConfig.class` so I attempted to add the `LegacyConfig` initialization to the `BeanConfig` class. Attempts via constructor and an `@EventListeneter` resulted in the same issue.